# Why does the command npm install -g expo-cli not working

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I'm trying to learn some React-Native and I actually have some problems with installing expo-cli!

I already installed Node.js on it's latest LTS version and when I execute the command `npm install -g expo-cli` it starts working till extracting `tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.11`.

I still getting this for hours without progression showing this error :

> tarball tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.11 ... seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

[this screenshot shows all the problem I had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5auR.png) 
Any solution please ?

Answer (score 3):

Update gems:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```

Documentation for fastline said.
 This is traveling ruby 2.2.2 packaged with a gem dependency on fastlane and with some expo specific scripts, included is a ruby interpreter for Linux.

Also npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the cmd with execute by administrator and install:
`npm install -g expo-cli`.